# LINQ filtering query for list of dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary, dynamic

I have a list of dictionary in the form of generic Linq query.Each dictionary object is a class with properties

> "Name","age","address"

Example:

```
public student class{
  public string Name {get;set;}  
  public string age {get;set;}
  public string address {get;set;}
  public string property {get;set;}
}
```

so i have list of student dictionary in the form of generic query.

```
List<object>listofStudentDictionaries=new list<object>();

listofStudentDictionaries
{
  content.....
  .............has all dictionaries of student class............... like
  all dictionary content goes inside the listofStudentDictionaries.

  Dictionary<string,object>dictionary=new Dictionary<string,object>();
  dictionary.add(Name,david);
  dictionary.add(age,22);
  dictionary.add(address,asfdsdfs);
  Dictionary<string,object>dictionary=new Dictionary<string,object>();
  dictionary.add(Name,rogers);
  dictionary.add(age,20);
  dictionary.add(address,zczxc);
  Dictionary<string,object>dictionary=new Dictionary<string,object>();
  dictionary.add(Name,richard);
  dictionary.add(age,17);
  dictionary.add(address,gfhghfg);
}

IQueryable<T> query=listofStudentDictionaries.AsQueryable();
```

Now how would I filter this query based on column name like student Name or age.

I want to return the query which is student entity where `student name="david";`

I tried all of these, but it didn't work......

```
query.ToList().Where(x=>((IDictionary<string, object>)x)[Name] == david);

query.ToList().Where(p => (dynamic)p[Name] == david);
```

I get this error

> cannot apply indexing of type array to expression of type T.

None of these returns the entity where `name = david`.

How to achieve this using Linq. Please help.

Comment: Yup i know. just gave a sample. just want to apply filter to generic query using Linq .

Comment: if you are creating student dictionary, why are you not adding student object  to the dictionary ?

Comment: Basically iam not creating student dictionary , iam creating a generic dictionary<string,object> composing of student entities  and adding all dictionaries to list of objects list<object>.so i can add even dynamic properties to it during run time .         so finally applying filter to  generic query is my aim.

Answer (score -1):

A dictionary isn't the best way of going.  Use Linq like code below

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            student.students = new List<student>() {
                new student() { Name = "david", age = 22,  address = "asfdsdfs"},
                new student() { Name = "rogers", age = 20,  address = "zczxc"},
                new student() { Name = "richard", age = 17,  address = "gfhghfg"}
            };

            List<student> query = student.students.Where(x => x.Name == "david").ToList();
        }
    }
    public class student
    {
        public static List<student> students {get; set;}
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public int age{get;set;}
        public string address{get;set;}
        public string property {get;set;}
    }
}
```

Comment: var query = database.students.Queryable();
want to apply column filter to query. and  also i have used  some dynamic properties during run time so using dictionary so i can combine dynamic properties with static properties.and then finally apply column  filter on generic query .

Comment: So in that case i might need dictionary because of dynamic properties.

Comment: If you have dynamic properties then the class would be a : List<object> properties {get;set}.  The choice of using linq or a dictionary would depend  1) The number of students. 2) Speed of getting results 3) Memory Usage.  For very large number of students I would recommend using a database like SQL Express which you can download for free from MSDN.com.